# Transform assoc array in recursive assoc array of itself

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, logic

Probably I did not write the question in the title well but I'll try to clarify through a couple of examples:
I've an array like this, it's my first array:

```
Array(
    ELEMENT1(
        subelement1.1
        subelement1.2
        subelement1.3
    )
    ELEMENT2(
        subelement2.1
        subelement2.2
        subelement2.3
    )
    ELEMENT3(
        subelement3.1
        subelement3.2
        subelement3.3
    )
)
```

And this is what I would be able to obtain as a result

```
Array(
    ELEMENT1(
        subelement1.1
             ELEMENT2(
                subelement2.1
                     ELEMENT3(
                        subelement3.1
                        subelement3.2
                        subelement3.3
                    )
                subelement2.2
                     ELEMENT3(
                        subelement3.1
                        subelement3.2
                        subelement3.3
                    )
                subelement2.3
                     ELEMENT3(
                        subelement3.1
                        subelement3.2
                        subelement3.3
                    )
            )
        subelement1.2
             ELEMENT2(
                subelement2.1
                     ELEMENT3(
                        subelement3.1
                        subelement3.2
                        subelement3.3
                    )
                subelement2.2
                     ELEMENT3(
                        subelement3.1
                        subelement3.2
                        subelement3.3
                    )
                subelement2.3
                     ELEMENT3(
                        subelement3.1
                        subelement3.2
                        subelement3.3
                    )
            )
        subelement1.3
             ELEMENT2(
                subelement2.1
                     ELEMENT3(
                        subelement3.1
                        subelement3.2
                        subelement3.3
                    )
                subelement2.2
                     ELEMENT3(
                        subelement3.1
                        subelement3.2
                        subelement3.3
                    )
                subelement2.3
                     ELEMENT3(
                        subelement3.1
                        subelement3.2
                        subelement3.3
                    )
            )
    )

)
```

I would like to understand what is the name of this type of interaction between the array and, if possible, a logical explanation to perform this operation.

Comment: Just wondering: what's the practical use-case for such an array? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I would like to create a generic system of categorization, based on N elements that intersect between them

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you want to do a simple reorganization of data. Assuming you want to join certain products from various manufacturers to several distinct categories, ideally selects them, for example, in a query or condition, and set this array. In good practice:

...

```
$subelements = array(
    'ELEMENT1' => array(
    'subelement1.1' => 'sector 1',
    'subelement1.2' => 'sector 10',
    'subelement1.3' => 'sector 10'
    ),
    'ELEMENT2' => array(
    'subelement2.1' => 'sector 5',
    'subelement2.2' => 'sector 1',
    'subelement2.3' => 'sector 7'
    ),
    'ELEMENT3' => array(
    'subelement3.1' => 'sector 2',
    'subelement3.2' => 'sector 7',
    'subelement3.3' => 'sector 10'
    )
);

foreach($subelements as $key => $value)
{
    foreach($value as $key2 => $value2)
    {
        $example[$value2][$key][] = $key2;      
    }
}

print_r($example);
```

...